# Fill form pdf with flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, pdf, pdf-generation

I'd like to fill a pdf form with flex.
Data are on my air application and I want to use those to fill a pdf file store on my computer.
Do you have an idea to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For PDF generation I've used [AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/). It works well once you figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for those answers but I don't find how to fill form with that.

Comment: So you want to edit an already existing PDF form? I'm not aware of a solution besides just opening the form up in a PDF reader (Adobe Acrobat, etc). Why not just have a normal Flex form to fill out? Then if you wanted a PDF of that filled out form, you can generate it with AlivePDF?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried AlivePDF with the alivepdf-template extension (they're both available on Google Code)?

Here's a sample of how to use the extension: http://gonzalo.huerta.cl/?p=3